# sharepoint newform with secondary newform webpart of another list

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, dataformwebpart

I have a "primary newform" of list 1 
which contains a "secondary newform dataformwebpart" of list 2.

I want enter values for "primary list 1" AND values for "secondary list 2" in one dialog. I want to save the values both in list 1 AND list 2 with one Save button.

The problem is:
When I press the "Save" Button, only the values of list 1 
( the primary newform webpart ) will be saved.

How can I fire /trigger the values of "secondary list 2" newform to be saved?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the ribbon save and the form save buttons by adding css or jquery into a content editor webpart on your page.  Also add a custom save button and replicate the default save buttons style by adding the class attribute and on click event write code to click both the save buttons.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will try this... I found out when pressing the "Save" Button from List 2, all fields will be saved ( also List 1 ). Therefore I try some javascript "fire save commit" button for both lists.